# Maximum value with multiple select statements

Tags: sql-server-2012

Can you please help me to get MAX AuditId(from CheckDetailAddendumA table ) value from the below query.

```
Select * from CheckDetailAddendumA
Where BusinessDate = '20041110'
and AuditID in (select AuditID from payments where paymentid in (select PaymentID from PaymentLinks where BusinessDate = '20041110' and ItemID = 11451163))
Order by AuditID
```

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Can you just do `select MAX(AuditID)`?

Comment: I tried with select MAX(AuditID) i am getting only Maximum AuditID value. but i am not getting all columns from CheckDetailAddendumA table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
   Select * from CheckDetailAddendumA
    Where BusinessDate = '20041110'
    and AuditID = (select MAX(AuditID) from payments where paymentid in 
                     (select PaymentID from PaymentLinks where BusinessDate = '20041110' and ItemID = 11451163))
```